# How to establish authorized request with keystone using python-openstack client API v3

Tags: python-2.7, openstack, keystone

I have problems with python-openstackclient library.When i run this code to authorize with keystone:

```
from keystoneclient import session
from keystoneclient.v3 import client
from keystoneclient.auth.identity import v3
password = v3.PasswordMethod(username='idm',password='idm',user_domain_name='idm')
auth = v3.Auth(auth_url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3',auth_methods=[password],project_id='idm')
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
keystone = client.Client(session=sess)
keystone.users.list()
```

Im getting this error:
keystoneclient.openstack.common.apiclient.exceptions.Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401)

But when i try openstack client program:

```
openstack user list
```

It gives me good output.
I have next global variables in my .bashrc:

```
export OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:35357/v3
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3
export OS_TENANT_NAME=idm
export OS_USERNAME=idm
export OS_PASSWORD=idm
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
export OS_URL=http://127.0.0.1:35357/v3
```

What could be the problem with that python code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
from keystoneclient import session
from keystoneclient.v3 import client
from keystoneclient.auth.identity import v3
auth = v3.Password(auth_url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3',user_id='idm',password='idm',project_id='2545070293684905b9623095768b019d')
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
keystone = client.Client(session=sess)
keystone.users.list()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but after applying proposed solution I was getting :

> keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to
>   establish connection to http://192.0.2.12:35357/v2.0/users:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.0.2.12', port=35357): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /v2.0/users (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

Note that my auth_url='https://myopenstack.somewhere.org:13000/v3',

It turns out that the client was discovering and using services on a interface which by default is 'Admin', and is unreachable for me. When forcing the interface to **Public** it works :

```
keystone = client.Client(session=sess, interface='Public')
```